# Cloud function to add/remove the url of a file from Firebase Database that has been added to/removed from Firebase Storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to implement a feature in an app which will list out all the file-names in a ListView and clicking the specific list item will show the contents of the file. I don't really know JavaScript and am also very new to Cloud functions. I wrote a small function which adds metadata to firebase whenever a file is added to firebase storage but it ends up adding the data even when the file is deleted.
Here is the code

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.urls = functions.storage.object().onChange( event => {
    const file = event.data;
    const metadata = file.metadata;
    console.log(metadata);
return admin.database().ref("/").set(metadata); });
```

Can someone please tell me what changes I could make in the above to add urls instead of metadata and also remove the same if the file is being removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Firebase documentation section [Detect resourceState and other event attributes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events#detect_resourcestate_and_other_event_attributes):

> The [`resourceState`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.storage.ObjectMetadata#resourceState) attribute for an event has the value `"exists"` (for object creation and updates) or `"not_exists"` (for object deletion and moves).
>
> ```
> // Exit if this is a move or deletion event.
> if (resourceState === 'not_exists') {
>   console.log('This is a deletion event.');
>   return;
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks @Frank. That solves a major part of the problem. I can't seem to find any code to remove data from firebase database though. Is there some function that can be called to do that?

Comment: I was referring to a function call in the cloud function @Frank, so that I can delete what I want to from firebase database after `console.log('This is a deletion event.');`, not the one in Android. I'll be really grateful if you can tell me something like that.

Comment: Continuing my previous comment. Deleting just the way I add to the database using `return admin.database().ref("/").set(metadata);`

Comment: Sorry, misclick in the navigation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#delete_data. Somehow this section is missing from the Admin SDK documentation, but the code works in the Admin SDK too.